# Alternative to shutil.copyfile

Tags: python, py2exe

I need an alternative to the shutil module in particular shutil.copyfile.

It is a little known bug with py2exe that makes the entire shutil module useless.

Comment: And what's the bug?

Comment: `shutil` works fine with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), you could give it a go.

Comment: the bug is documented here: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t674268-problem-with-py2exe-conversion.html

was not too happy to run into this as shutil is quite useful

Answer (score 3):

ummm

```
os.system("cp file1 file2") ?
```

Im not sure why shutil wouldnt work in py2exe ... you probably have to explicitly tell py2exe to include that library ...

Comment: sure as long as you got cygwin or mingw and have the bin in your path ... or use the windows equivelent  (`copy`)

Comment: If someone is distributing an exe file, they probably can't assume the user has cygwin or mingw, so I think `copy` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Using os.system() will be problematic for many reasons; for example, when you have spaces or Unicode in the file names.   It will also be more opaque relative to exceptions/failures.

If this is on windows, using win32file.CopyFile() is probably the best approach, since that will yield the correct file attributes, dates, permissions, etc. relative to the original file (that is, it will be more similar to the results you'd get by using Explorer to copy the file).

Answer (score 1):

If a simple call to `os.system()` works for you, then go with that solution.  It's just one line of code!

If you really want something like shutil.copyfile, you can grab what you need from the Python source. Here's the relevant code from Python-2.7.3/Lib/shutil.py:

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)

def _samefile(src, dst):
    # Macintosh, Unix.
    if hasattr(os.path, 'samefile'):
        try:
            return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
        except OSError:
            return False

    # All other platforms: check for same pathname.
    return (os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(src)) ==
            os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(dst)))

def copyfile(src, dst):
    """Copy data from src to dst"""
    if _samefile(src, dst):
        raise Error("`%s` and `%s` are the same file" % (src, dst))

    for fn in [src, dst]:
        try:
            st = os.stat(fn)
        except OSError:
            # File most likely does not exist
            pass
        else:
            # XXX What about other special files? (sockets, devices...)
            if stat.S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode):
                raise SpecialFileError("`%s` is a named pipe" % fn)

    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
            copyfileobj(fsrc, fds
```

If you don't mind ignoring all the error checking, you can distill that down to:

```
def copyfile(src, dst):
    length = 16 * 1024
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
            while True:
                buf = fsrc.read(length)
                if not buf:
                    break
                fdst.write(buf)
```

Comment: While 16 KB buffer? File system buffers are usually much bigger - even on embedded system. If memory serves me well, it was 0x80000 (512 KB) on Symbian 6 years ago.

Comment: I don't know why shutil.copyfile defaults to a 16KB buffer.  A bigger buffer sounds reasonable to me.